# How to establish HTTPS connection without importing certificate file to KeyStore?

Tags: java, ssl, https

Is there any way to establish an HTTPS connection without importing the certificate to keyStore?

Currently , I am importing the certificate to `myKeyStore`

```
 keytool -import -alias aliasOfCertifiate -file myCertificateFile.cer -keystore myKeystore
```

using a `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` object to establish the HTTPS connection. But, as per a new requirement, my HTTPS client may need to communicate with thousands of web servers. So, I believe, importing the certificate might not be a good idea.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224607/getting-images-from-https-with-java

Comment: bayou... thanks for your reply. I saw the thread you have mentioned. But, my main requirement "not to add it to the trust store".

Comment: yes - both answers will accept any server certificate without keystore being involved.